# How can I express this mathematical English statement "Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets" in the first-order language?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm studying analysis 1 and I have a question.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Then $X \cup Y$ is finite and $\#(X \cup Y) \le \# X + \# Y $. ($\#X$ means the cardinality of $X$)

This is the statement that I proved and I proved it by using mathematical induction just because I felt like I should use it.

And I know that mathematical induction skill is used for proving some statement like this form "For any natural number~,"

But if I could see the above bold statement as a conditional statement, then I think the antecedent would be "Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets." and the consequent would be "Then $X\cup Y$ is finite and $\#(X\cup Y) \le \#X+\#Y$."

So I thought that the first order logic expression for the antecedent would be like this
"$\exists n\, \exists m\, \#X=n,\ \#Y=m$" because of the definition of a finite set(a set is finite iff it has cardinality $n$ for some natural number)
and the whole expression would be "$\exists n\ \exists m\, \#X=n,\ \#Y=m \rightarrow \exists a\, \#(X\cup Y)=a\land a\le n+m$"

But if it's expressed like this, there's no reason to use mathematical induction because there is no expression $\forall$ in that formula.

What is the problem?

Comment: Correct; no induction needed. Induction is used to *prove*, not to *express*.

Comment: But note that you are using concepts and symbols of set theory. No "pure" FOL formula can express "finite".

Comment: Why did you use MathJax only for symbols? You can use it for letters and # too.

Comment: @Stefan Octavian does it matter?  use mathjax for all symbols?

Comment: you can check here for a quick guide to mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Well, I'm just saying that the math in your question looks strange and hard to read, the variables and operators are not spaced appropriately and the fonts are mixed.

Comment: @Stefan Octavian I'm sorry.. could you be a little more specific? where should I fix it?

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA I used mathematical induction to prove that statement. so I think there should be $\forall$ symbol for that expression. but I don't know how to do it

Comment: What is # supposed to be?

Comment: @The Pointer I'm sorry I didn't realize that. It's a notation for the size of a set

Comment: You mean the cardinality? # is not the notation for cardinality.

Comment: @thepointer oh.. what is it then? Terence tao's book uses it for cardinality, only finite case maybe?

Comment: My fault, I just noticed that # is sometimes used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality (although, I'd never seen it)

Comment: I don't think the # notation works with MathJax. Perhaps it is better to use the conventional $\vert \vert$ notation for cardinality. See my edit of the first part of your post.